# How to get median in mysql if group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, window-functions, median

My mysql version is 8.+.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `loss` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `circle` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kpi_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kpi_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data for the table `loss`:

```
insert  into `loss`(`date`,`circle`,`district`,`kpi_1`,`kpi_2`) values 
('2020-09-20','101','delhi',90,100),
('2020-09-20','102','Punjab',80,10),
('2020-09-20','104','delhi',90,90),
('2020-09-20','104','New Delhi',20,10),
('2020-09-20','104','Punjab',45,23),
('2020-09-20','104','New Delhi',4,13),
('2020-09-20','104','New Delhi',7,150),
('2020-09-20','104','New Delhi',80,40),
('2020-09-20','104','New Delhi',80,50),
('2020-09-20','104','New Delhi',NULL,NULL);
```

Query:

```
select date,circle,district,count(*) as total_rows,sum(kpi_1),sum(kpi_2) from loss
group by date,circle,distrcit
```

I can get all aggregates, but how to find median as well?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: just median of kpi_1,kpi_2 for group by date,circle,district as sum(kpi_1),sum(kpi_2) gives result

Comment: Edit your question and post the expected result in tabular text format.

Comment: @forpas , is there any  median  aggregated function, median which can return middle value for each group by of set

Comment: Just a suggestion, try to find out the median on the application layer instead of the database layer. This will reduce the load on database server by a great extent.

Comment: No there isn't a function for median.

Comment: @forpas there is any solution for that , i am new in mysql

Comment: You did not post your expected result yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have an aggregate median function or the-like - not even as a window function, as in MariaDB.

One workaround using window functions is:

```
select date, circle, district, count(*) cnt, sum(kpi_1) sum_kpi1, sum(kpi_2) sum_kpi2,
    avg(case when rn1 in (floor((cnt + 1)/2), floor((cnt + 2)/2)) then kpi1 end) media_kpi1,
    avg(case when rn2 in (floor((cnt + 1)/2), floor((cnt + 2)/2)) then kpi2 end) media_kpi2
from (
    select l.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by date, circle, district order by kpi1) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by date, circle, district order by kpi2) rn2,
        count(*)     over(partition by date, circle, district) cnt
    from loss
) l
group by date, circle, district
```

This assumes that you want to aggregate records by date, circle and district, as show in your original query. If you want another set of columns, then you can change both the `group by` clause and the `partition`s of the window functions.